# Writing an Image Streaming Server in C# using Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, bitmap

I am writing a server using sockets to stream my desktop captures.

A method (controlled by a timer) returns  a Bitmap in every 100 ms after capturing the desktop and converting it to Bitmap. 
What I have planned to do is to write that bitmap to a global buffer and on connection of each client write that buffer to the relevant socket (of the client) in a "while loop" until the connection is closed. Each client is served by using the Thread Pool.

Then I have two questions...

1. Until the client is disconnected "while loop" is a "while(true) loop". When many clients are    connected,as multiple loops are running, this way may use the processor heavily. So how to handle it?
2. When many clients are connected, as I am using one buffer, waiting time for the clients may be high due to locks.So is there a proper way other than this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of a poling loop to look for new images, why not use events and have each connection subscribe to the "new image" event.

Comment: Thanks.. I feel it will help me